# Problem refreshing modal from within modal that was dynamically loaded with JQuery AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, bootstrap-modal

Edit: So after continuing to research, I stumbled across the reason this isn't working and it has to with banding the new element to the already running JQuery listener.  Problem is, Javascript and JQuery are not my strongest points. Can anyone help me understand how to add a success to the first jquery script that triggers a binding once the ajax append is done?

I have this code to load a dynamic modal then show it when this link is clicked:
`<a href="#" id="1" class="messageWindow link">Link</a>`

```
$('.messageWindow').on('click',function(){
    $('#messageBody').load('https://webaddress.com/process/fetch-message.php?m='+(this.id),function(){
        $('#viewModal').modal({backdrop: 'static', show:true});
    });
});
```

Then I have this code waiting for a link inside the modal to be clicked.
`<a href="#" class="messageReply btn btn-info" id="1">Reply</a>`

```
$('.messageReply').on('click',function(){
    $('#messageBody').load('https://webaddress.com/process/fetch-message.php?messageReply='+(this.id),function(){   
    });
});
```

The initial AJAX loading of the modal and showing the modal works just fine. The problem I cannot figure out is how to completely reload the entire modal from a link that exists inside the dynamic modal. Will the 2nd jquery script just ignore clicks because the modal was not present at page load?
I've also tried adding the function to show:true on the second script but that doesn't seem to have any effect.

I've also confirmed that my fetch-message.php script is working and producing the correct data.
I am trying to load a modal to display an email, then reload the modal when the reply button is clicked with a text area to reply in.

Comment: You need to have an eventListener on the original page targetting your button inside the modal

Comment: Do you want to replace the entire modal or just the body?

Comment: The listeners are on the original page. And yes the entire modal is replaced due to needing to change header and footer of modal too.

Comment: `$('body').on('click', '.messageReply', function () {})`. See: https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/